# How to iterate through DOM elements in react and add/remove classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am beginner to react and I am unable to iterate through `div` elements.
 Each of these `div` elements (shown in the code) have a common `className="step"` initially but once the button `Next` is clicked I want 1st div to have `className="step current"` .
Once `Next` is clicked again 1st div element should have `className="step done"`(remove current and append done) and 2nd div element would have `classname="step current"`

I was able to toggle the className from `"step"` to `"step current"` in the following code but I am facing difficulty to traverse the div elements and add or remove the class.

```js
class NavBar extends React.Component{
    state = {
        addClass : false
    }
    handleClick=()=>{
        this.setState({addClass: !this.state.addClass});
    }
    render(){
        let arrowClass = ["step"];
        if(this.state.addClass){    
            arrowClass.push("current");
        }
        return(
            <div id="navbar-div">
                <div className="arrow-steps clearfix">
             1.       <div className={arrowClass.join(' ')}>
                        <span> Step1</span>
                    </div>
             2.       <div className={arrowClass.join(' ')}>
                        <span>Step2</span>
                    </div>
             3.       <div className={arrowClass.join(' ')}>
                        <span> Step3</span>
                    </div>
             4.       <div className={arrowClass.join(' ')}>
                        <span>Step4</span>
                    </div>
             5.       <div className={arrowClass.join(' ')}>
                        <span>Step5</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="nav clearfix">
                    <a href="#" className="prev">Previous</a>
                    <a href="#" className="next pull-right" onClick={this.handleClick}>Next</a>
                </div>
                </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NavBar />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.current {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.done {
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The classes `step, current and done` are defined in the css file.

Comment: Should re-think whole approach and use array of objects to pass to render and manipulate the array instead or use indexing for the various classes

Comment: For your next question, [here's how I created that runnable snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/) from your code block.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! I shall take care henceforth.

Comment: @user7098526 - It just helps you get good answers. :-) The key thing is to make sure you have an MCVE in the question where possible (which you did, and that's why I was able to convert it to a snippet).

Comment: @user7098526 use the `className` attribute instead of the `class` for the `.nav`, `.prev` `.next`

Comment: @MuraliKrishna Yeah! Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than writing the steps explicitly, put them in an array, and then remember where you are within that array with an indexing variable. Here's the minimal-changes approach to doing that with your code (see comments):

```js
class NavBar extends React.Component{
    state = {
        steps: ["Step1", "Step2", "Step3", "Step4"],
        current: 0 // <== Step1 is the current step
    }
    prevClick = () => {
        // Move to previous step, note we use the callback version of setState,
        // see https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous
        this.setState(({current}) => ({current: Math.max(0, current - 1)}));
    }
    nextClick = () => {
        // Move to next step
        this.setState(({steps, current}) => ({current: Math.min(steps.length - 1, current + 1)}));
    }
    render() {
        // Get the steps and the current index
        const {current, steps} = this.state;
        // Render them, checking the position of the step (`index`) relative to `current`
        // and outputting the relevant class name.
        // I changed your `div`s to an ordered list so we get automatic numbering
        return (
            <div id="navbar-div">
                <div>{current}</div>
                <ol className="arrow-steps clearfix">
                    {steps.map((step, index) =>
                        <li key={index} className={`step ${index < current ? 'done' : index == current ? 'current' : ''}`}>{step}</li>
                    )}
                </ol>
                <div className="nav clearfix">
                    <a href="#" className="prev" onClick={this.prevClick}>Previous</a>
                    <a href="#" className="next pull-right" onClick={this.nextClick}>Next</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NavBar />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.current {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.done {
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously, that just shows the basic approach, you'll want to modify it. If you have any information other than just the step text, you might make the array entries objects rather than just strings.

(Note: Using `index` as the `key` on those `li`s is only valid if you don't add/remove entries in the array of steps.)

---

Side note: As Murali Krishna [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915027/how-to-iterate-through-dom-elements-in-react-and-add-remove-classes/52915207?noredirect=1#comment92740543_52915027), you had `class` rather than `className` on the div containing the previous/next links and on those links; I've changed those to `className` above.

Comment: @MuraliKrishna - Doh! Thanks, fixed! (And `class` => `className`)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Any idea how to apply range checking?

Comment: @user7098526 - Just do the check in the `setState` callback (`Math.min` and `Math.max`, for instance).

Comment: I tried doing this `({current}) => (({current}<5) ?{current: current + 1}:{current : 4})` in `setState` but it didn't work. Can you please explain where I am wrong?

Comment: @user7098526 - If you have only four steps, they're indexes 0, 1, 2, and 3, so that `<5` check should be `<3`. **But**, don't hardcode it, use `steps.length` instead: `this.setState(({steps, current}) => ({current: current < steps.length - 1 ? current + 1 : current}));` But I'd probably use `Math.min`; I've updaed the code in the answer to do range checking.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do that but there's a more React'ish way. That is to use state to store the class you wanna add. So when you change the state (using setState) it will auto re-render and set the class.

Eg.

```
class NavBar extends React.Component{
    state = {
        status: "current"
    }
    handleClick=()=>{
        this.setState(prevState=>{
            if(prevState.status === 'current'){
                return {status:"done"}
            }else{
                return {status:"current"}
            }
        })

    }
    render(){
        return <button className={"step " + this.state.status} onClick={this.handleClick}>Hello</button>
    }
```

Comment: No, that breaks [one of the fundamental rules of React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous): If setting state based on existing state, you **must** use the callback version of `setState` and use the state object it passes you. (This also doesn't really do much to answer the question, it just toggles all the steps together.)

Comment: Also, this is an at least semi-professional environment. Please don't use child- or text-speak like "wanna." It's "want to."

Comment: @Kashif Siddiqui  Each div is not clickable I have a separate `Next` button at bottom. This doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Oh yeah it could be a button as well. The important thing is to refer state in your element `className={"step " + this.state.status}`